# What are the Options for jQuery Animated Effects?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-effects

A lot of the jQuery (and jQuery UI) functionality allows for animations to occur when showing/hiding elements. One of the irksome things about their otherwise-thorough web site is their lack of definitions of the animation keywords you can use. I'm aware of `slide`, `fadeIn`, and `fadeOut`. I know I've used others in the past as well. Is there a definitive list of options somewhere?

Comment: +1, for a question I've meant to ask before, but never remembered to =)

Comment: @Etdashou's answer is most relevant as of Jul 2015.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's also the **jQuery UI** effects in addition to the standard [jQuery effects](http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/).

The only list I could find of them were on the demo page:  http://jqueryui.com/docs/effect/

This includes stuff like slide, shake, puff, blind, etc...

This main landing page on the [jQuery UI Effects page](http://jqueryui.com/docs/Effects/Methods) has links to demos of some of the jQuery animation effects (show, hide), but not all (like fade in/out) and also links to the jQuery UI effects.

But overall, I don't think there is a comprehensive jQuery / jQueryUI list.

Answer (score 4):

[Jquery Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/)

That's a list of all the Effects.

Answer (score 2):

I really like this page: http://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/effect/easing.html

And as previously said, this is also useful: http://jqueryui.com/effect/

Answer (score 1):

Here is a good place to start for the baked-in effects in jQuery:

http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/

Answer (score 0):

Found a good resource on this topic...

http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/

This not only offers several easing options but also a test area where you can explore several options.